# Why value is taken from value-mdpi if I'm working with Galaxy Nexus

Tags: android

I have `dimens.xml` defined in both `values` and `values-mdpi` folders. I'm expecting the value for `Galaxy Nexus` device (which is `xhdpi`) to be taken from `values` but actually it is taken from `values-mdpi`. Why is that so? Thank you.

Comment: "For default I use 14sp value, for mdpi I need 8sp value. That's it." -- that makes no sense. You're saying that a 10" tablet should have a different font size than does another 10" tablet, just because the screen density is different? Bear in mind that `sp` already takes density (and font scale) into account.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You must create a folder for `values-xhdpi`.
`values` is the default folder, but if you specify a folder with a qualifier (here, `values-mdpi`) the system will use the best apropriated folder with a qualifier (here `values-mdpi`)

If you add a `values-hdpi` folder, it will be used over `values-mdpi` for a screen at xhdpi.

If you add a `values-xhdpi` folder, it will be used over the previous two folder for a screen at xhdpi.

Answer (score 4):

Check http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch

You'll see that pixel density qualifiers are NOT removed from how Android resolves where to look for resources.

Comment: So how can I specify default value and the value for `mdpi` devices?

Comment: How are your default values different than mdpi? Why just mdpi and not have hdpi, xhdpi, etc.

Comment: For default I use 14sp value, for mdpi I need 8sp value. That's it.

Comment: @MorrisonChang: The only places that I have seen the "screen pixel density is the one qualifier that is not eliminated due to a contradiction" scenario demonstrated is with drawables. I'll have to test the OP's case sometime and see if I can reproduce it, as that would suggest that density is treated the same way for non-drawables as for drawables, which is news to me. Admittedly, I don't usually see non-drawables depend upon density, and I *seriously* doubt that changing font size based on density is the right answer for the OP.

Comment: @MorrisonChang: Fascinating! Android does the same thing for non-drawables as drawables with respect to density resource set qualifiers. An app with `res/values/strings.xml` and `res/values-xxhdpi/strings.xml`, run on an `-xhdpi` device, pulls from `res/values-xxhdpi/` rather than the default set. Thanks for triggering this line of research!