# Values in /values-normal-mdpi overriding values in /values

Tags: android, android-resources, dimensions

I'm a little confused, hopefully somebody can clarify for me.

I have a dimens file in /res/values, but I want to override some of those default dimens for normal-mdpi screens. i.e. I want to have special dimens for normal-mdpi that won't affect the rest of my screen size / density buckets.

However, the dimens I put in res/values-normal-mdpi/dimens.xml are affecting other screen sizes / resolution buckets (e.g. large-xhdpi). I would expect large-xhdpi to still pull from res/values and not be affected by what I put in rev/values-normal-mdpi.

Does anyone why? And how I can achieve the desired effect?

Comment: Please clarify your question, on the one hand you're saying you want the values in res/values-normal-mdpi to override res/values, but then you're complaining that they are '...overriding the ones I have in /res/values...'. So it is unclear what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks Tom, posting updated.

Comment: hello karim you have create two folder in res  one is values,values-normal-mdpi

Comment: Hi Nilesh, I have these folders created. The problem is that the values in values-normal-mdpi are being used in other density devices (e.g. xhdpi). I'd expect xhdpi devices to use the values in /values, not /values-normal-mdpi.

Answer (score 1):

[This SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16019318/2577986) is very similar, and the answers to it very helpful ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16019769/2577986)) ([2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16019526/2577986)). Basically, the Android system will find the best match using [these methods](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch). For screen density, it will find the closest match and take that. It will only use `res/values/dimens.xml` if the dimension isn't in any of the density-specific directories.

In this case, create another version of `dimens` in any directory that will be a "better match" for the other devices that you want to support (ex: `values-hdpi`), and put the default values of the dimens that were overriden in there.